# How to get imageview reference in compound drawables in android?

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview

If you have a textview+image like this:

```
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/calendar" />
```

How can you get the ImageView reference from the textview reference in java code?
I want to set a click event for the image, not the textview.

Does anyone know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`textView.getCompoundDrawables()` will get the `drawableLeft`, `drawableRight`, `drawableTop`, and `drawableBottom` items. And `setCompoundDrawables()` to set them.